# How to implement jQuery live() on jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"].item').each(function(){
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone(true).appendTo($(this));

        for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
            next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone(true).appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
```

As you can see, the code is cloning an element on carousel scroll.

The issue is that events on the element, a jQuery `.hide()` and `.show()`, is not being triggered because the clone is not cloning data events.  I tried setting `clone(true)` but that does not work. It works before the clone happens (before scroll) but not after. Elsewhere I read that someone fixed a similar issue with `.live()`, but I have no idea of how to implement `.live()` here.  Any jQuery / Javascript gurus?

Comment: I don't see any call's to `hide` or `show`?

Comment: @Tryingtoimprove look at https://www.wineofthemonth.co.za/40-wine-club - before the four blocks are scrolled, if you click on any of them, it hides a currently displayed nav-tab div and shows another.  After scroll, the divs are no longer hidden/shown.

Comment: So it is your `click` event that is not triggered?

Comment: @TryingToImprove Yes, it seems that clone does not propagate data attributes, which I use to identify the target element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `live` is deprecated and you should instead use `on`.. .

According to the comments, it is not the `hide()` nor the `show()` commands that works, because the `click` event is not getting triggered on the dynamically added DOM elements.

To resolve this issue you can use `on`.

```
$('.carousel').on('click', '.item', function(e) {
    var $this = $(e.target); // should reference the `.item`

    //... perform the click event here for every item
});
```

Now the click event is attached to the element which contains the clickable items, so you can add and remove elements in the container and items with the classname `item` will trigger the event.

Comment: Thanks mate, that certainly led me in the right direction.